# summarize data to one point of a different year and plot them in a graph

Tags: pandas, data-science

I want to summarize data point to different years. 
So I want to plot a graph of with different years, and summarize from a specifies attribute a graph so let's day coins of the year 2011 -2015

So I choose as Data Frame pandas 
I used:

```
Summerize the data point (way 1)
testn = test.groupby(by=[test.index.year,test.index.month]).sum()
print(testn['SalesDateTime'])
print (type(testn))
```

This give me a Error. 
The Error tells me that there is no attribute year or month?

```
    enter code here

    Summerize the data point (way 1)
    testn = test.groupby(by=[test.index.year,test.index.month]).sum()
    print(testn['SalesDateTime'])
    #print (type(testn))

    Summerize the data point (way 2)
    nieuw = test.groupby(by=[test.index.month, test.index.year])
    print(nieuw)

    testn.plot("SalesDateTime","Coins",)
    plt.show(testn)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no `DatetimeIndex`, so need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
test.index = pd.to_datetime(test.index)
testn = test.groupby(by=[test.index.year,test.index.month]).sum()
```

Or:

```
testn = (test.groupby(by=[test.index.year.rename('year'),
                          test.index.month.rename('month')]).sum().reset_index())
```